# How to stop Telerik AJAX Grid Postback on page change

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2013, telerik-ajax

I have **ASP.NET Web User Control page** with **Telerik Ajax grid** implemented inside to display records from Sharepoint Server 2013.

On paging, the telerik grid performs postback, hence fetching all records on page change. Thus encountering the performance issue.

Is there any way to stop postback on paging?

Or Is there any possible way to solve this issue?

Comment: You mean to say that the page is refreshing when you just want the grid to fetch a new page of data in ajax?  Post some code.

Comment: Yes. Page is refreshing when I tried to get new page data. But as per below answer from Muhammad Aftab, we can not prevent PostBack on paging and sorting

Answer (score 0):

You can not prevent `PostBack` on `paging` and `sorting` as it rebinds the grid every time. The below link contains the details about your problem. Kindly visit it.

https://www.telerik.com/forums/prevent-postback

[image]

Comment: Yes. That's true. Thank you.

Comment: Alternate solution for this will be changing Telerik AJAX grid to Kendo UI Javascript grid